# Google Cloud Platform single load balancer for UDP as well as TCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, instance, load-balancing

I am setting up the GrayLog cluster in `GCP`. I've done with the setup today with 3 nodes. However there's problem I'm facing in load balancer. In `GCP`, it provides `HTTP`, `TCP`, and `UDP` load balancer. What I need is to send the messege through UDP as well as `TCP` is needed. In short, `TCP` and `UDP` both should be used by single load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually possible now, but you will need to reserve a named IP address ahead of time

```bash
gcloud compute addresses create your-reserved-ip \
  --addresses=a.b.c.d \
  --subnet=your-subnet \
  --region=your-region
```

You can now create two separate forwarding rules which both use `your-reserved-ip`. The first listens on TCP/53 and the second listens on UDP/53.

```bash
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create dns-tcp-frontend \
  --region=your-region \
  --load-balancing-scheme=INTERNAL \
  --subnet=your-subnet \
  --subnet-region=your-region \
  --backend-service=dns-tcp-backend \
  --backend-service-region=your-backend-region \
  --ip-protocol=TCP \
  --address=your-reserved-ip \
  --ports=53
```

```bash
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create dns-udp-frontend \
  --region=your-region \
  --load-balancing-scheme=INTERNAL \
  --subnet=your-subnet \
  --subnet-region=your-region \
  --backend-service=dns-udp-backend \
  --backend-service-region=your-backend-region \
  --ip-protocol=UDP \
  --address=your-reserved-ip \
  --ports=53
```

The above assumes you have two backend services, the first listening for DNS requests on TCP/53 named `dns-tcp-backend`, and the second listening for DNS requests on UDP/53, named `dns-udp-backend`.

When the forwarding rules are created, they will both listen on `your-reserved-ip`

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation there are:

[Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal)

> Google Cloud Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing is a regional load
>   balancer that enables you to run and scale your services behind an
>   internal load balancing IP address that is accessible only to your
>   internal virtual machine (VM) instances. **Each internal TCP/UDP load
>   balancer supports: Either TCP or UDP traffic (not both)**

[External TCP/UDP Network Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network)

> Google Cloud external TCP/UDP Network Load Balancing (after this
>   referred to as Network Load Balancing) is a regional, non-proxied load
>   balancer. **Each network load balancer supports either TCP or UDP
>   traffic (not both).**

Answer (score -1):

**Network Load Balancing** could be a solution. This is is a non-proxied load balancing service for UDP and TCP. You can use forwarding rules to balance the load based on incoming packet characteristics such as address, port or protocol type.

The backend could be an Instance group or Target pool resource.

A limitation that you should be aware of is that this is a **regional** service, i.e. traffic can be balanced between VM instances that are in the **same region**.

For more information, see [Setting Up Network Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/).